# Can I respond "I will" to this

Tags: expressions

"She's on her way. Let me know when she's here."

"I will."

Is "I will" natural here or how else could you respond to this other than "OK" or "Yes"?

Comment: Sure. ***I will*** = affirmative *I will **let you know when she's here.*** Compare the standard form of a wedding ceremony: ***Do you** [take this woman, blah blah,...]? - **I do** [take her].*

Answer (score 1):

"I will" is fine.  "Will do" would be somewhat more idiomatic, at least in my dialect.